# Git branch is not working as I am expecting

Tags: git, github

Okay so I am new to using git..and I thought I understood the concept of branching, but now I am confused.

Lets say I have a master.

I create a branch called branch1.

```
git checkout -b branch1

master
*branch1
```

I made some changes on branch1, but I realized I have to do something else before finishing my work on branch1.

So I go back to master

```
git checkout master

*master
branch1
```

and create a new branch called branch2.

git checkout -b branch2

```
master
branch1
*branch2
```

Since I didn't commit my changes on branch1, I am expecting my branch2 will not have branch1 codes...but I am seeing the changes made from branch1.

Am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you were in branch1 when you made the changes, those changes are not really "in" branch1 until you commit them.

From `$ git help checkout`:

> Local modifications to the files in the working tree
>   are kept, so that they can be committed to the <branch>.

If, on the other hand, you commit your changes to branch1 *before* switching back to master, then when you `$ git checkout master`, git will revert the files in your working directory back to the snapshot that master points to, as you are expecting.

If for some reason you really want to avoid committing your changes to branch1, but still work on a different branch without those changes, you might consider using `$ git stash` to stash your changes, then switch to your new branch and do the work you need to, then switch back to branch1 and do `$ git stash pop` to get back your stashed changes.

Comment: Thanks for the details. All my confusions are resolved!

Answer (score 4):

> Since I didn't commit my changes on branch1, I am expecting my branch2 will not have branch1 codes

Working copy (staged + unstaged changes) is the same for all branches. And what you see is not the branch1 changes, but the working copy changes.

Once you commit your changes in branch1, you'll no longer see them in branch2 or any other branch.

Comment: Now I understood why I am seeing all changes when I do git status. Is there a command where I can commit changes made in branch1?

Comment: `git checkout branch1`. then `git add` your changes to move them to `staged`. And then `git commit -m "commit message"` will do it.